# Raise custom error in command-line parsing

Tags: go, go-flag

I'm using the [flag](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) module to parse my flags, but want to have at least one positional argument. How do I show the usage help when not enough positional arguments are present, as I would in python with [`parser.error`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error)?

Currently, I am manually calling `os.Exit`, but that feels really cumbersome for what should be a simple error:

```
package main

import "flag"
import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
  flag.Parse()
  if flag.NArg() != 1 {
    println("This program needs exactly one argument")
    flag.Usage()
    os.Exit(2)
  }
  fmt.Printf("You entered %d characters", len(flag.Args()[0]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do things like this, I use the `log` package.

```
package main

import "flag"
import "fmt"
import "os"
import "log"

func main() {
  flag.Parse()
  if flag.NArg() != 1 {
    log.Fatalln("This program needs exactly one argument")
  }
  fmt.Printf("You entered %d characters", len(flag.Args()))
}
```

`log.Fatal()` and it's sister methods (`log.Fatalln()`, `log.Fatalf()` etc) are all helpers that simply do `log.Print()` and then follow it up with `os.exit(1)`.

Edit -- Adding link
http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatalln

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't output the usage.